# Problems when embedding LaTeX \dot and \hat into Microsoft Word via MathML

Tags: ms-word, latex, mathml

From David Carlisle's answer to the post [Embed LaTeX math equations into Microsoft Word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115065/94132), I learned that \dot{z} in LaTeX can be translated in MathML as:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
    <mover>
      <mi>z</mi>
      <mo>&#x02D9;<!-- ˙ --></mo>
    </mover>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

However, when I pasted the code above into Microsoft Word, I got a dot far away from the letter z (shown on the left in the image below), which looks quite inappropriate compared to the result I got from typing "\dot{z}" directly in Word (shown on the right). Similar problems occur for \hat and \ddot.

[image]

Is there another set of MathML codes to be pasted in Word that can present the dot above a letter more properly, i.e., that can put the dot closer to the letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not obvious which part of the post you referenced shows that particular construct, but to make your code work you need to add accent="true" to the mover element:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
    <mover accent="true">
      <mi>z</mi>
      <mo>&#x0307;<!-- ˙ --></mo>
    </mover>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

As far as I can see, Word would typically use a different sequence, more like this (after a bit of code editing):

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
  <mover accent="true">
    <mrow>
      <mi>z</mi>
    </mrow>
    <mo>&#x0307;</mo>
  </mover>
</math>
```

You could also achieve the layout like this, but then you are really encoding a different piece of math, saying that your identifier (the thing in the  element) is a dotted z, whereas the previous approach where you put the dot in the  element is saying that the identifier is a z and the dot is an operator:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" display="block">
  <mrow class="MJX-TeXAtom-ORD">
    <mi>z&#x0307;</mi>
  </mrow>
</math>
```

Comment: Thank you! The codes you provided work well.

I was referring to David Carlisle's answer (I added this to my question) and also the comment below it, which mentioned the tool https://github.com/idf/LaTex2Word-Equation . This tool is very convenient, but also lacks accent="true".

Comment: @isend Thanks for the edit. AFAICS in MathML3 the fact that the &#02D9 is listed in its Operator Dictionary as being an "accent" may mean that you should not have to specify 'accent=' . Even the main author of the Math features in word suggests that is the case in one of his blog articles at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/murrays/2018/03/31/representation-of-math-accents/ . So it's difficult to see why it is necessary.